# Multiple Inheritance with abstract class

Tags: python, qt4, multiple-inheritance

I have a class like this

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Observer(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, dataMsg):
        pass

Observer.register(tuple)
```

I need to be able to Multiply Inherit like this

```
class MyTable(QTableWidget, Observer):
    def __init__(self, data):
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, 0, len(data))
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(data)
```

But if I do this I get this error:

```
tableColumns = QStringList(['A' , 'B'])
atable = MyTable(tableColumns)

 class MyTable(QTableWidget, Observer):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

**Is there a way around this?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will come back to bite me, but I solved it through aggregation instead of inheritance. So instead:

```
class MyTable(Observer):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.myTable = QTableWidget(0, len(data))
        self.myTable.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(data)

    def getWidget(self):
        return self.myTable
```